# Powerpoint - slide master - link not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have Powerpoint for Mac v 16.81 (24011420) on a Macbook pro 2018 macos 12.7.2

I set up a slide master with 3 placeholders, which cover the entire slide in 3 slices with no overlap. I then put a shape on top to cover the entire slide. This shape has a link to the first slide.

My slides have 3 items, title, question, answer, all of which are being put into the proper placeholders. I can click on the background of the slide, and I am taken to the first slide. All is good.

However, if I click on the actual text from any of the 3 objects, I am taken to the next slide, not the first slide. You can see the mouse change from an arrow when hovering over the text to a finger when hovering over any part of the background. As the text changes from slide to slide, the area to click on changes. The clicking on any text does not follow the link.

I want the link object to be the top layer so when the user clicks anywhere on the screen, they are taken to the first slide. It is like the text in the placeholder is on being placed on top of the link, but only the text, not the full placeholder itself.

I want the user to be able to click anywhere on the slide and be taken to the first slide. If they click on the text, it does not work.

Any help is appreciated. thanks

slide master config - ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/yERVY.jpg ;

mouse between words, working properly - ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RC2H.jpg  ;

mouse on text, not working properly - ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf9kp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> > I set up a slide master with 3 placeholders, which cover the entire slide in 3 slices with no overlap. I then put a shape on top to cover the entire slide. This shape has a link to the first slide.

When PPT creates a new slide based on a layout that includes placeholders, it copies the placeholders to the slide, which puts them on the top layer. But because the shape you've added atop the placeholders is not itself a placeholder, it stays BEHIND the text placeholders in the slides you've created, so the text placeholders "see" any clicks, not the shape.

I think you'll need to delete the shape from the master/layout and, once your text is all in place, create the linked shape on the first slide where you want it to appear, then copy/paste it to any other slides where you need it.